# how to create button inside card?

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

I have a lot of difficulties while designing web sites. I'm using bootstrap to create card.

I'm using the following code to create the card:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mb-2"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">                               
        <h3 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside this card, I would like to generate [close] button in the same line with `<h3>` tag. Could you please help this out? I tried a lot ways but I was not able to figure it out.

After getting answer, I changed button into icon with the following codes.

```
<div class="row mb-2"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">                               
        <h3 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
            Special title treatment 
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The close icon is located in the bottom of  line. how I can put the close icon to the top of  line?

Comment: Which tag do you want it in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following solutions:

**solution #1 (button left aligned - after text of `<h3>`):**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mb-2"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">                               
        <h3 class="card-title d-flex">Special title treatment <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-3" href="#">Close</a></h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**solution #2 (button on the right side):**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mb-2"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">                               
        <h3 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between w-100">Special title treatment <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Close</a></h3>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `justify-content-center` you can use `justify-content-between` and wrap the text in a span. This would display the headline on the left and the close button on the right.

Comment: @AnnaLee - You're welcome. don't forget to [mark as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Bootstrap [close icon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/close-icon/), it uses float right, so just put it in the `h2` tag, and then use `w-100` to make the h2 full width..

https://www.codeply.com/go/pm3smAGdUk

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                    <h3 class="card-title w-100">
                        Special title treatment
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                             <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well. thank you so much, if possible, could I ask one more question? :) when I do click that close icon, there comes up blue border, how I can remove that blue border when clicking?

Comment: Looks like the .scss file is uses `.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5);
}` I added this style to remove the blue appearing on the .btn `.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
    box-shadow: none !important;
}` Depending on how you wish to organise your scss

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have short knowledge of CSS. From what I see in the codes, button's class is 'close', how does this relevant with .btn-primary.focus in terms of bootstrap?